# JavaScript - onCopy event and blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that listens for copy event, displays some animation (i.e: "successfully copied!"), and then unfocuses the text field.

```
$('.textfield').on('copy', function() {
    doAnimation();
    this.blur();
});
```

The problem that I'm running into is that this event is triggered before the text is copied to the clipboard so the blur() call causes the text selection to be lost and nothing copied onto the pasteboard.

Is there anyway to have this event triggered after the text is copied?

Comment: try generating the doanimation and blur code on doc ready. e.g  $('.textfield').on('copy', function(){dothis()}); $(document).ready(function(){function dothis(){doAnimation();
    this.blur();}});

Comment: @AlK why would that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a timeout should fix it:

```
$('.textfield').on('copy', function() {
    var $_self = $(this);
    doAnimation();    
    setTimeout(function(){$_self.blur();},0);
});
```

Comment: This works. If you are using underscore _.defer() does exactly this.